# How to get all groups from google cloud identity using gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-groups

I am using the [gcloud beta](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/identity/groups/search) command to search the groups in GCP.

The problem is I have 1700 groups, and after x number of groups command generates nextpagetoken and I have to enter it manually to rerun the command. Is there any way I can automate it? i.e, store the next page token in a variable and pass it to the following command.

```
gcloud beta identity groups search --organization="5487965215"  --labels="cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum" --page-size=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation can be done in different ways, one of them using a while loop that retrieves `nextPageToken` from response.

You can run this script on the Cloud Shell and change the Org ID. Group names will be saved on group.txt file

```
# setup
ORGANIZATION_ID="..." 

# get groups list
echo -n > groups.txt
GCLOUD_ARG_PAGE_TOKEN=""
RUN=1
while [ $RUN == 1 ] ; do
  gcloud beta identity groups search \
    --organization="${ORGANIZATION_ID}" \
    --labels="cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum" \
    --format=json \
    --page-size=1000 \
    ${GCLOUD_ARG_PAGE_TOKEN} \
  > response.json   <response.json jq -r ".[0].groups[].groupKey.id" >> groups.txt   NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN="$(<response.json jq -r '.[0].nextPageToken')"
  if [ "$NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN" == "null" ] ; then
    GCLOUD_ARG_PAGE_TOKEN=""
    RUN=0
  else
    GCLOUD_ARG_PAGE_TOKEN="--page-token=$NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN"
  fi
done
```